# Why can't isn't my action mailer working with Send Grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble sending activation and password reset emails. I'm building the Sample App from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and have encountered this problem near the end of Chapter 12. After deploying to Heroku (project is called evening-river-42952), I opened the app and attempted to send a password reset email to an existing user.

I received a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" message. I went back to the app and decided to try and create a new user, activate it via email, and request a password reset for this new user. But just creating the new user prompted the same "We're sorry" message, and I haven't received any activation links.

I was having issues before retrieving the activation emails, but seemed to resolve the issue (my account with Send Grid was suspended). All seemed to be working until now. My tests written for the Mailers are passing. Any help would be most appreciated! (If the code below isn't sufficient I will gladly upload more, or you can see the whole app on my Github account. My username is miagenovese and the repository is sample_app.)

Heroku Logs:

```
    2018-03-13T03:29:18.020071+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:29:18.020008 #6] FATAL -- : [c17c714b-296f-47c6-a37c-171a2e034f9f]   
2018-03-13T03:29:18.019948+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:29:18.019861 #6] FATAL -- : [c17c714b-296f-47c6-a37c-171a2e034f9f]   
2018-03-13T03:29:18.020011+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:29:18.019943 #6] FATAL -- : [c17c714b-296f-47c6-a37c-171a2e034f9f] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
2018-03-13T03:29:18.020154+00:00 app[web.1]: [c17c714b-296f-47c6-a37c-171a2e034f9f] app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:13:in `create'
2018-03-13T03:29:18.020150+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:29:18.020084 #6] FATAL -- : [c17c714b-296f-47c6-a37c-171a2e034f9f] app/models/user.rb:62:in `send_password_reset_email'
2018-03-13T03:29:18.343417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com request_id=2cb0d864-f1c7-431c-9f3c-89d41e3c80dc fwd="73.150.134.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
2018-03-13T03:31:58.585281+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.585170 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce] Started GET "/login" for 73.150.134.10 at 2018-03-13 03:31:58 +0000
2018-03-13T03:31:58.587401+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.587322 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce] Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2018-03-13T03:31:58.607376+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.598227 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-03-13T03:31:58.610770+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.610685 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.611631+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.611555 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.4ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.618597+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.618518 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.619556+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.619484 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.619151+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.619076 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.619903+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:31:58.619831 #10]  INFO -- : [5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce] Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-03-13T03:31:58.609008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com request_id=68b51b65-471f-4925-98d5-ef8d2984d0b8 fwd="73.150.134.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
2018-03-13T03:31:58.621851+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com request_id=5f6467ba-d886-4dea-bc2f-73098769fbce fwd="73.150.134.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=41ms status=200 bytes=3496 protocol=https
2018-03-13T03:32:00.178502+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/signup" host=evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com request_id=037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89 fwd="73.150.134.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=3467 protocol=https
2018-03-13T03:32:00.146526+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.146397 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89] Started GET "/signup" for 73.150.134.10 at 2018-03-13 03:32:00 +0000
2018-03-13T03:32:00.148605+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.148530 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2018-03-13T03:32:00.151894+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.151808 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-03-13T03:32:00.156089+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.156005 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.7ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.162691+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.162604 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.166650+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.166567 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.8ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.169949+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.169877 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee 9]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.170622+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.170554 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.171096+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.171020 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:00.171664+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:00.171596 #10]  INFO -- : [037f1a51-f47f-4e8c-bc50-24ab2914ee89] Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:39.523098+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.523005 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Started POST "/signup" for 73.150.134.10 at 2018-03-13 03:32:39 +0000
2018-03-13T03:32:39.524750+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.524674 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2018-03-13T03:32:39.524925+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.524848 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sAEWjc4ImCrdeYQDxWNWe33bd4m307CnsksScmBk3y8D92mfnSI4SBArNK9z68ScUNkU7lGjm8aaDegEeeimww==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Test User 1", "email"=>"hahyl@amail.club", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2018-03-13T03:32:39.608278+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.608157 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
2018-03-13T03:32:39.617490+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.617407 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "hahyl@amail.club"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-03-13T03:32:39.694966+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.694851 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Test User 1"], ["email", "hahyl@amail.club"], ["created_at", "2018-03-13 03:32:39.618143"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-13 03:32:39.618143"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$uvnZX.vljrrfSRgMwAb.duzmBy4aPb2040xaytFtX5yIDh7CVMNl."], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$iendy286HJWAwtXH4zR5Oelj7zTdoXqOz/R117CAVF7.W6CNHzmY6"]]
2018-03-13T03:32:39.697133+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.697061 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]    (1.7ms)  COMMIT
2018-03-13T03:32:39.701977+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.701892 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
2018-03-13T03:32:39.702840+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.702771 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.8ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:39.703175+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.703108 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
2018-03-13T03:32:39.703796+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.703718 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.5ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:39.705612+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.705491 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 8.0ms
2018-03-13T03:32:39.931964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/signup" host=evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com request_id=553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474 fwd="73.150.134.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=410ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928767+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.928624 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Sent mail to hahyl@amail.club (222.9ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928844+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.928758 #10] DEBUG -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Date: Tue, 13 Mar 2018 03:32:39 +0000
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928847+00:00 app[web.1]: From: noreply@example.com
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928849+00:00 app[web.1]: To: hahyl@amail.club
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928851+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5aa74657aca91_a3169f4c629a4@16b93889-b671-4421-8086-dbf03b7786ca.mail>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928852+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Account activation
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928854+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928856+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928861+00:00 app[web.1]:  boundary="--==_mimepart_5aa74657abf4b_a3169f4c62848";
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928863+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928865+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928866+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928867+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928869+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5aa74657abf4b_a3169f4c62848
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928870+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928872+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928873+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928875+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928876+00:00 app[web.1]: Hi Test User 1,
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928878+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928880+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to Micro App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928881+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928883+00:00 app[web.1]: https://evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com/account_activations/Nexyvh0nacOqftjJA_Koog/edit?email=hahyl%40amail.club
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928884+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928886+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5aa74657abf4b_a3169f4c62848
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928887+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928889+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928891+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928892+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928894+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928896+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928897+00:00 app[web.1]:   <head>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928899+00:00 app[web.1]:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928900+00:00 app[web.1]:     <style>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928902+00:00 app[web.1]:       /* Email styles need to be inline */
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928903+00:00 app[web.1]:     </style>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928905+00:00 app[web.1]:   </head>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928906+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928908+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928909+00:00 app[web.1]:     <h1>Micro App</h1>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928911+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928913+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi Test User 1,</p>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928914+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928916+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928917+00:00 app[web.1]:   Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928919+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928920+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928923+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="https://evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com/account_activations/Nexyvh0nacOqftjJA_Koog/edit?email=hahyl%40amail.club">Activate</a>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928924+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928926+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928927+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928929+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5aa74657abf4b_a3169f4c62848--
2018-03-13T03:32:39.928930+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-03-13T03:32:39.929177+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.929098 #10]  INFO -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 404ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930227+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.930146 #10] FATAL -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930301+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.930234 #10] FATAL -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930303+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930390+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.930329 #10] FATAL -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474]   
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930482+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-03-13T03:32:39.930423 #10] FATAL -- : [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] app/models/user.rb:50:in `send_activation_email'
2018-03-13T03:32:39.930485+00:00 app[web.1]: [553c4cce-7ab5-40cd-bb49-dc2ea6df6474] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Production.rb

```
   Rails.application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # Code is not reloaded between requests.
      config.cache_classes = true

      # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
      # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
      # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
      # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
      config.eager_load = true

      # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
      # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
      # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
      config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

      # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
      # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
      config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = false

      # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

      # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
      # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

      # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

      # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
      # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
      # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
      # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

      # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
      config.force_ssl = true

      # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
      # when problems arise.
      config.log_level = :debug

      # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
      config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

      # Use a different cache store in production.
      # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

      # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
      # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
      # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "sample_app_#{Rails.env}"
      config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

      # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
      # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
      config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      host = 'https://evening-river-42952.herokuapp.com'
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
      ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
        :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
        :port           => '587',
        :authentication => :plain,
        :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
        :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
        :domain         => 'heroku.com',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }

      # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
      # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true

      # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

      # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

      # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
      # require 'syslog/logger'
      # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

      if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
        logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
        logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
        config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
      end

      # Do not dump schema after migrations.
      config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  end
```

Development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Do care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'http://sample_app-c9-miagenovese.c9users.io'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: Did you set user name and password of sendgrid in enviroment variables ?

Comment: Have you provisioned sendgrid's addon?

Comment: The error is clear. Bad username / password. Are Heroku environment variables for sendgrid correctly set?

Comment: I'm not sure to anyone's question... sorry I'm really new at this. Could anyone specify how I would set the username and password for the environment variables? I don't even have an environment.rb file.